# How to print a string in a proper format if my string is having new line character in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, newline

I am having an issue with this piece of code:

```
NSString *msg=[[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"msg" forElement:root] ];  
lblText.text=msg;
```

The variable `msg` contains the string `"Good Job\nThanks"`. When I assign 'msg' to the label text property, the string is shown with the newline character `\n` but I would like the string to be displayed like this instead:

```
Good Job

Thanks
```

/shivam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your string seems to come from a XML file, try to enter the XML's New Line character `&#10;` instead of `\n`. Otherwise it will print the characters `\`and `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set number of lines that label could have to unlimited number:

```
UILabel *label;
label.numberOfLines = 0;`
```

Comment: It works perfect for me with "Good Job\nThanks". Are you sure that it is not "Good Job\\nThanks"?

Comment: Yes, I checked. Your string has `\ ` before `\n` : "Good Job\\nThanks"

Comment: let me check, because its coming from xml